# Extracting data from cakephp 3 sessions table

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using [Database Sessions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions) in my CakePHP 3 application as I wish to display list online employees(users) in the admin panel of the site.

I want to retrieve the logged in employee(user)s' session info (at least user id) so that their details can be displayed in the list.
*data* column of the **sessions** table contains session info but I don't know how to extract specific info from it. I want *Auth* info from it. It contains serialized data concatenated with session key somehow.

**Data Sample**

> Config|a:1:{s:4:"time";i:1457067440;}Flash|a:1:{s:4:"auth";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:7:"message";s:52:"Woopsie,
>   you are not authorized to access that
>   area.";s:3:"key";s:4:"auth";s:7:"element";s:13:"Flash/default";s:6:"params";a:1:{s:5:"class";s:5:"error";}}}}registrar_id|i:2;registrar_name|s:10:"Gaurav
>   Makhecha";unread_site_updates_ids|s:1:"1";

Can anyone please guide me on how I can achieve this the best way.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450008/cakephp-3-display-logged-in-online-users-list/35451529#35451529 (Disclosure: I wrote the answer)

Comment: The session data is serialized by PHP. Try using [session_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php) to unserialize it. That said having a record in sessions table doesn't necessary mean user is actually logged in. He could have just closed his browser window and the session record won't be cleared until garbage collection is run.

Comment: Googling also came up with https://gist.github.com/phred/1201412

Comment: @Sevvlor Thank you for that answer. I had read that but using Database Sessions would give me better performance I thought.

Comment: Thank you @ADmad. Yes, I know about that. I tried but could not find any solution to get accurate(real time) data of logged in users. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the session db is the best place to implement that feature. Maybe you could use something else...

Just thinking out loud, maybe a logged in user could, at every request, renew some kind of flag. That could be done as well every X minutes with JS. That way, you filter out "old" flags and display fresh ones, which should display active users in the moment.

There are probably better ways to do that, but I think that using the session db wouldn't be the best way.

Comment: Yes @Eber its not the best way to get accurate data. Am still in search of a better option which can give desired result without affecting performance and resource usage.